# The fixed top:0 right:0 item is not correctly showed on mobile when virtual keyboard is there, how to fix?

Tags: html, css, mobile

Here is my code:

```css
body {}
#holder {
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
      position:fixed;top:0; right:0;opacity:.5;background:black;width:60px;height:30px}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="holder">
<svg version='1.1' id='L9' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='-18 40 100 100' enable-background='new 0 0 0 0' xml:space='preserve'><rect x='20' y='50' width='4' height='10' fill='#fff' transform='translate(0 13.1135)'><animateTransform attributeType='xml' attributeName='transform' type='translate' values='0 0; 0 20; 0 0' begin='0' dur='0.6s' repeatCount='indefinite'></animateTransform></rect><rect x='30' y='50' width='4' height='10' fill='#fff' transform='translate(0 13.5532)'><animateTransform attributeType='xml' attributeName='transform' type='translate' values='0 0; 0 20; 0 0' begin='0.2s' dur='0.6s' repeatCount='indefinite'></animateTransform></rect><rect x='40' y='50' width='4' height='10' fill='#fff' transform='translate(0 0.219867)'><animateTransform attributeType='xml' attributeName='transform' type='translate' values='0 0; 0 20; 0 0' begin='0.4s' dur='0.6s' repeatCount='indefinite'></animateTransform></rect></svg></div>

<p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p><p>dummy</p>
<textarea></textarea>

</body>
```

I am adding a loading effect to my page. The effect is an SVG contained in a div, and I put the div on the `top:0`, `right:0` with `position:fixed`.

However, the loading div is not showing up on my iPhone if the virtual keyboard is there.

I find it very hard to view the snippet on StackOverflow so I made a picture to demonstrate this:

[image]

When the user invokes the keyboard, the loading div is "pushed" up. However, this doesn't happen every time. In a few attempts, there would be likely 20% chance to get it right (the loading not going above).

Is there any fix to this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a media query in CSS to write specific code that when the height is X amount (X being equal to the screen height, minus the keyboard height, on a phone). You may have to write some more CSS but it would fix the issue. let me know if that works.

Comment: How can I get the keyboard height if the users are from different phone models?

Comment: fair question. I would have gone into more explanation, but i seen your rep was 2600+ so i didnt bother. You're going ot have to do some research, or just code it for the "lowest common denominator" figure out a (reasonable) range of screen heights, then you just have to subtract keyborad pixel sizes of android/ios and if youre feeling nice, windows phones. : ) i'm gonna look for you right now...

Comment: ...did some checking, it looks complicated. i would just play around and eyeball it. after a few times you will have a good idea, and for other cases, the user can still scroll. one of those things...